# Process killed by SIGHUP after read returns ERESTARTSYS

Tags: linux, debugging, strace

We have some application which calls a PHP script which connects to an Oracle DB to do certain things. :) This does not work out well sometimes.

We are now running the PHP part via strace from the beginning.

This is how it looks when everything works ok (everything works out, the DB connection is built, the query executed, the DB is again disconnected, etc.):

```
10:30:17.935486 connect(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1521), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.1.1.55")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
10:30:17.935546 times(NULL)             = 2908590046
10:30:17.935569 brk(0xda4000)           = 0xda4000
10:30:17.935594 poll([{fd=8, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 60000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLOUT}])
10:30:17.940338 getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [519270883345301504], [4]) = 0
10:30:17.940368 fcntl(8, F_GETFL)       = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
10:30:17.940388 fcntl(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR) = 0
10:30:17.940408 getsockname(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(62498), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.22.30")}, [16]) = 0
10:30:17.940437 getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [-4193870156763480064], [4]) = 0
10:30:17.940458 getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [-4193870156763409068], [4]) = 0
10:30:17.940483 setsockopt(8, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
10:30:17.940506 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
10:30:17.940652 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x1, ~[ILL ABRT BUS FPE SEGV USR2 TERM XCPU XFSZ SYS RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7198b2b920}, {0x1, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f7198b2b920}, 8) = 0
10:30:17.940725 write(8, "\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x3b\x01\x2c\x0c\x41\x20\x00\xff\xff\x7f\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\xa2\x00\x46\x00\x00\x08\x00"..., 232) = 232
10:30:17.940781 read(8, "\x00\x08\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00", 8208) = 8
10:30:17.974177 write(8, "\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x3b\x01\x2c\x0c\x41\x20\x00\xff\xff\x7f\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\xa2\x00\x46\x00\x00\x08\x00"..., 232) = 232
10:30:17.974247 read(8, "\x00\x29\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x3b\x0c\x41\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x29\x51\x41\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"..., 8208) = 41
10:30:17.976465 write(8, "\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x06\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\xde\xad\xbe\xef\x00\x9a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"..., 164) = 164
....
```

This is how it looks when everything does not work ok:

```
10:23:24.888170 connect(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1521), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.1.1.55")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
10:23:24.888241 times(NULL)             = 2908548738
10:23:24.888263 brk(0xda4000)           = 0xda4000
10:23:24.888287 poll([{fd=8, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 60000) = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLOUT}])
10:23:24.889769 getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [519270883345301504], [4]) = 0
10:23:24.889807 fcntl(8, F_GETFL)       = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
10:23:24.889827 fcntl(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR) = 0
10:23:24.889845 getsockname(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(62473), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.22.30")}, [16]) = 0
10:23:24.889873 getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [-8374476973480591360], [4]) = 0
10:23:24.889892 getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [-8374476973480520364], [4]) = 0
10:23:24.889915 setsockopt(8, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
10:23:24.889936 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
10:23:24.890062 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x1, ~[ILL ABRT BUS FPE SEGV USR2 TERM XCPU XFSZ SYS RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f2ee24b4920}, {0x1, [PIPE], SA_
RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f2ee24b4920}, 8) = 0
10:23:24.890129 write(8, "\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x3b\x01\x2c\x0c\x41\x20\x00\xff\xff\x7f\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\xa2\x00\x46\x00\x00\x08\x00"..., 232) = 232
10:23:24.890186 read(8, 0xd705a6, 8208) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
10:23:24.907853 --- SIGHUP (Hangup) @ 0 (0) ---
10:23:24.908708 +++ killed by SIGHUP +++
```

This happens *sometimes* and the application (or at least the PHP script and the connection to the DB) just gets killed. That's bad.

- What do you make of the above straces?
- Can we tell who is killed by who?
- Why would read() return ERESTARTSYS?
- What does `SIGHUP (Hangup) @ 0 (0)` tell us exactly?

Comment: All it really means is someone sent a SIGHUP to your PHP script, which killed it. Is this running within a web server, or are you running the PHP script in some other context (SIGHUP is also sent when a controlling terminal tty is closed)

Comment: The PHP binary is invoked from another application. Probably that application prematurely terminates and doesn't give PHP the time to finish?

Answer (score 2):

Your process got sent a `SIGHUP`, which caused the normal action of exiting.

Can't tell who did it.  Try a newer version of strace.  From what I can tell, going all the way back to version 4.6 from 2011 it should display more information.  The version of strace you are using is from prior to 2011 and the `@ 0 (0)` supplies the PC of the process when the signal was received and the address associated with the signal from `siginfo_t`.  Neither will tell you anything about this problem.

A newer version will supply something like this:

```
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=25064, si_uid=1000} ---
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
```

This first is another process sending the SIGHUP.  The second is one sent automatically because of certain events.

The latter can happen when the controlling terminal of the process closes or when the session leader exits because its terminal closed.  If you determine it's the kernel sending the signal, then I'd look at your process while it's running and examine the "sid" and "tty" columns in the ps output.  That will tell you the session leader and terminal responsible for causing the `SIGHUP` to be sent.  Maybe sometimes your script has a controlling terminal and sometimes not?

The session leader would usually be the parent process that started your script, or the parent of that process, or the parent of that, etc.  Looking at ps output and "sid" will tell you.  If that leader process exits and has a controlling terminal, everything under it gets a `SIGHUP`.  The way to solve this would be either have the leader not exit until the PHP process is finished, or at some point detach from that session or terminal.  Usually a daemon or server process should not associated with a terminal.  See `daemon()` and `setsid()`.

Comment: `# rpm -qa | grep strace`
`strace-4.5.18-10.22.1`

Comment: I must not have been looking at the source I thought I was.  In that version it is printing out the address where the signal was received and the address associated with the signal, as if it was a seg fault.  Neither is useful to you.  The additional information was added in version 4.6 from 2011.